# Unable to use Neo4j 1.9.M05

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

When I add Neo4j 1.9.M05 to my project dependencies (with maven), I'm getting the following error in eclipse:

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:tests:1.9.M05: UnresolvableModelException: Failure to find org.neo4j:parent:pom:1.9.M05 in http://m2.neo4j.org/releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of neo4j-release-repository has elapsed or updates are forced

This seems to make sense because the URL "http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/parent" does not exist. Was anybody able to use 1.9.M05 already? Is there another public repository where I can find this dependency?

ps: does anybody know when the neo4j-cypher-dsl module gets updated to 1.9.M05?

Comment: I think it is fixed now? The parent pom should be in maven central.

Comment: That's right, by Andres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you can bypass this problem by manually placing [this parent pom](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/1.9.M05/pom.xml) in your local maven repository (or upload it to your companies nexus, or ...).

Comment: And now it's available on http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/neo4j/parent/1.9.M05 as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent has not been deployed, I would suggest you file a bug report with the authors, as this won't work. They'll either have to deploy the parent, of spin off a new release.

Comment: Idd, already done that in their user group, see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/neo4j/Lvk9JCE8Hw8.