# Unable to use spring-data-neo4j:2.3.1.RELEASE with Gradle

Tags: java, neo4j, gradle, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using gradle and need to bring the latest Spring Data Neo4j into my project.

My build file includes -

```
repositories {   
      mavenCentral()

      maven{
          url 'http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl/1.9.M04'
      }
}

dependencies {
     compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:2.3.1.RELEASE'
}
```

My question seems almost the same as this one:

[Unable to use Neo4j 1.9.M05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268437/unable-to-use-neo4j-1-9-m05)

and this one:

[Unable to find neo4j-cypher-dsl version 1.9.M04 anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653128/unable-to-find-neo4j-cypher-dsl-version-1-9-m04-anywhere)

When I run 'gradle build' I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
Could not find org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:1.9.
      Required by:
         :my_project > org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:2.3.1.RELEASE
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of `neo4j-cypher-dsl` in Maven Central is 1.7 (easy to find out on http://search.maven.org). If you need 1.9, you'll have to declare a repository that contains that version. Your (second) repository declaration is invalid because the URL doesn't point to a Maven repository but to a particular Maven module within that repository.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peter, I was able to get the build script right and point it to the alternative repo:

```
maven{
    url 'http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases'
}
```